# use select statement to get Data from a DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have DataTable containing three columns, **Name, Date and DialedNumber**. I want to get rows on the basis of DialedNumber column having phone number like **03001234567 ...**

I am filing datatable with an method return type is datatable.

```
{
DataTable dt = filldata();
}
```

Problem is how to use select statement to get rows having number 03001234567 or some other telephone number ?

Comment: .net or c# version would be helpful to someone in giving you a better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Suppose you have a variable `**string str**` which is having that telephone number which you want to get from that data table then you can use this

```
{
 DataTable dt = filldata();
 DataRow[] resut = dt.Select("DialedNumber ='" + str + "'");
}
```

It will return you those rows having same telephone number in column **DialedNumber.**

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
private void GetRowsByFilter()
{
    DataTable table = DataSet1.Tables["Table1"];
    // Presuming the DataTable has a column named Date. 
    string expression;
    expression = "DialedNumber ='03001234567 '";
    DataRow[] foundRows;

    // Use the Select method to find all rows matching the filter.
    foundRows = table.Select(expression);

    // Print column 0 of each returned row. 
    for(int i = 0; i < foundRows.Length; i ++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(foundRows[i][0]);
    }
}
```

## [DataTable.Select Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter from the start, not getting *all* table rows every time, you should adjust your SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE DialedNumber = @dialedNumber
```

and in C# use [`SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to add the `@dialedNumber` parameter to the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Linq to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386910%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string number = "03001234567";
var rows = dt.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(r => r.Field<string>("DialedNumber").Contains(number));
```

You even can project rows into strongly typed objects:

```
var people = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
             where r.Field<string>("DialedNumber").Contains(number)
             select new {
                  Name = r.Field<string>("Name"),
                  Date = r.Field<DateTime>("Date"),
                  DialedNumber = r.Field<string>("DialedNumber")
             };
```

Note: if you want to check exact match of dialed number, then instead of `Contains(number)` (which is equivalent of LIKE) use `== number`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Linq to DataTable like this

```
var results = from myRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
                          where myRow.Field<String>("DialedNumber") == "03001234567"
                          select myRow;
```